# My Javascript Content Gallery - Error Somewhere here

Tags: javascript, html

Question: Why does my script leave the content blank on the 7th content (ID:img_7)?

All of the content changed for ID img_1 - ID img_6 but when I hit that seventh interval, it's blank.

With my script, I set a variable ImageCnt to be zero, I check the length of an array of IDs, which will all be used in the function nextImage, which takes one parameter, 'direction', and I define my function to take care of the transitions: nextImage(direction).

```
<script>

    var backgroundId = new Array();
    var backgroundId = [
        "img_1",
        "img_2",
        "img_3",
        "img_4",
        "img_5",
        "img_6",
        "img_7",
    ];

    var ImageCnt = 0;
```

The left transition arrow will call the function nextImage with the parameter 'left' to let the function know which direction to increment ImageCnt, which controls the ID made clickable and visible by the function nextImage. For example nextImage('right') would tell the function nextImage to increment downward by 1. This makes it so that if the ID img_4 is being rendered through the script and the function nextImage is called with the parameter 'right', the

```
    function nextImage(direction) 
    {
            var i=1;
            while(i<8)
            {
            document.getElementById("img_" + i).style.opacity = "0"; //"un-render" the rest of the elements
            document.getElementById("img_" + i).style.pointerEvents = "none";//"un-render" the rest of the elements
            i++;
            }
```

Here (above) I use a while loop to force all IDs to "disappear" - the newly selected one will simultaneously reappear, and CSS will cause a very smooth, nice, flawless transition here.

```
        ImageCnt = (ImageCnt + (direction == "left" ? backgroundId.length-1 : 1)) % backgroundId.length;
```

Here (above) we're simply iterating through our pictures using ImageCnt to keep track of the selected image and it's right/left transition.

```
        document.getElementById("img_" + ImageCnt).style.opacity = "1";

        document.getElementById("img_" + ImageCnt).style.pointerEvents = "auto";
```

And finally, above, we append the number stored in ImageCnt to "img_" to select a specific ID to restyle. Opacity and pointer events are the key players here.

```
    }
```

And there you have it. I've done something wrong, if you can find the problem, help me out! I'm searching for the mistake :/

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EagyP/

My JS Fiddle is not working properly with the transitions, but at www.testing.agcomputers.net, where I am testing, it is working, albeit with that problem on img_7 - (I know it's not proper to post a link, I will remove this soon)

Comment: @Maple "img_7", ? I did try removing that comma

Comment: Might be a good idea to set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Please provide a working jsfiddle.

Comment: Get rid of the `var backgroundId = new Array();`, you don't have to do that as you're immediately overwriting it with an initialized array.

Comment: @Maple: That's only an issue in IE.

Comment: Your jsFiddle isn't working because you're using `onclick` attributes.  This requires that your functions be in the global scope.  To fix your fiddle, on the left, change `onLoad` to `no wrap <head>`.  http://jsfiddle.net/EagyP/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up your zero-index and one-index notation a little. `ImageCnt` goes from 0-6, your image list goes from 1-7.
Since (I assume) you have no img_0, it bombs out when searching the DOM for it.

My test seems to indicate that if you change your img_7 to be called img_0 you'll be set, though that solution is quick and dirty.

A more reliable solution would be to use the value stored in `backgroundId[ImageCnt]` to search on, like so:
`document.getElementById(backgroundId[ImageCnt])`
This makes the number (from `ImageCnt`) separate from the element name, allowing you to name the element anything you want as long as it is in your `backgroundId` array. (Which could be improved in other ways to be made unnecessary.)

Comment: Changing the img_7 ID in the css does not fix it.

Comment: And what do you mean by that, exactly (last sentence)

Comment: You already have a list of the elements stored in your `backgroundId` array, so instead of building the element name by concatenating `"img_"` and `ImageCnt`, just use `backgroundId[ImageCnt]` like so: `document.getElementById(backgroundId[ImageCnt])`

Comment: ah ok, trying that now

Comment: Yep! That fixed me up perfectly!